# Why is my javascript not being executed?

Tags: ajax, 8

I have a Drupal 8 form and I'm applying some custom javascript to it. I've added a JS file, and a libraries file for my module containing a reference to it, but the code doesn't run.

in **module_name/js/autocomplete.js**

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {

  Drupal.behaviors.modulename_autocomplete = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      jQuery(function() {
        // Doesn't work
        console.log('foo');

        // Doesn't work
        alert('bar');

      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

and in **module_name.libraries.yml**

```
module_name.autocomplete:
  version: 1.0
  js:
    js/autocomplete.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.ui.autocomplete
```

As the comments suggest, I see no console messages and no alert, so it's clear the behavior is not being executed.

What do I need to change for this to work?

Comment: Put an `alert` or `console.log` at the top of the `attach` function - does it run? If it does, your question is about general JS development and should move to StackOverflow. If it doesn't, then you can remove all of the jQueryUI related stuff as it won't be relevant to the Drupal problem

Comment: it does not alert and no log in console when do console.log

Comment: Ok, assuming there are no related errors in the console, it's going to be down to how you're adding the JS file in that case, because it's not being included in the page source. Is the module enabled? Have you rebuilt caches since adding the library? Are you sure your `dependencies` don't need to be one level further in?

Comment: I've changed your question so it's focused on the real problem (the jQueryUI autocomplete stuff is irrelevant), but there seems to be a part missing - where is the code that actually includes the library on a specific page? If the answer is "there isn't any", then that's your problem

Comment: is there any indentation problem in module_name.libraries.yml file ? i replaced the js with your code now,

Comment: No that's my mistake, ignore that one. Your indentation is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't attach your to your form:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'module_name/library_name';
```

Just a suggestion:

In your library yml it's unnecessary to append your module name to your library name.

Comment: As this is a content type form , where i can attach the js , its not a custom made form using form builder

Comment: You can use: "hook_form_alter" to change the behavior of an existing form.

Comment: Thanks , now am getting the alert , so now i can figure out the autocomplete functionality i guess

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich and so people like me don't waste their time answering the question

Answer (score 3):

If this is a content type form and you have defined this content type as a child of ContentEntityBase in your module, you should use the form builder that you have specified in your @ContentEntityType annotation.

For example:

```
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "anwalt_entity",
 *   label = @Translation("Anwalt"),
 *   handlers = {
 *
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\preosanwalt\Form\AnwaltEntityForm",
```

Now, in your class AnwaltEntityForm extends ContentEntityForm, you can add your library attachment like ssibal said:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $build = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

    $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'module_name.autocomplete';
    $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['x'] = ...

    return $build;
  }
```

You don't need hooks if you have OO :-)

Comment: the form builder for a content type is not clear , can you post a full fledged example to replace hook_form_alter ? How to define a class and structure and all . Will that class autoloaded when the content type is loaded ?

Comment: I'd suggest to use "drupal generate:entity:content" with https://drupalconsole.com/. It generates all the boilerplate stuff for you, and also the form_builder. Posting all the code is bit lengthy :-)